# Websockets adapter for Python Requests library

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-requests, zeep

I want to add a websockets adapter for Python requests library, was wondering if anyone has already implemented an adapter for this ?
Similar to the [HTTP Adapter](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/adapters.py#L101), but for websockets.

I'm trying to connect to a websocket endpoint (`ws://`) from **zeep**
(which uses **requests** library under the hood) and websockets aren't supported by **requests** library by default.
I want to add an adapter that can handle all `ws://` and `wss://` protocols with **zeep** (and **requests**) library

Answer (score 1):

a.) use `websockets` library (together with `requests`, if you really want to)

```
import asyncio
import requests
import websockets

async def send_message(message):
    async with websockets.connect("ws://echo.websocket.org") as websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)
        response = await websocket.recv()
        return response

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
response = loop.run_until_complete(send_message("Hello, World!"))
print(response)
```

b.) use `aiohttp` instead

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def send_message(message):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.ws_connect("ws://echo.websocket.org") as ws:
            await ws.send_str(message)
            response = await ws.receive()
            return response.data

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
response = loop.run_until_complete(send_message("Hello, World!"))
print(response)
```

c.) use `requests_html`

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

async def send_message(message):
    async with AsyncHTMLSession() as session:
        websocket = await session.ws_connect("ws://echo.websocket.org")
        await websocket.send_str(message)
        response = await websocket.receive()
        return response.text

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
response = loop.run_until_complete(send_message("Hello, World!"))
print(response)
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess i didn't specify all the details in my question.
The problem is that I'm using `zeep` library for SOAP requests (which uses `requests` under the hood) and I want to connect to a `ws://` endpoint.

I'll edit the original question